# Locking Mechanism for data stored in redis

Tags: c, redis, locking

Dears, I have a problem where multiple redis-clients are accessing a common structure stored in redis-server.

Requirements are as follows:-

1. If a particular redis-client is accessing the structure stored in redis-server (shall do read and write operation on the structure), no other redis-client should be able to access and wait for being released.
2. Every time other redis-client is accessing the structure, they should access the updated structure.

How can I put locking mechanism to fulfill this requirement in C Code.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Aren't redis transactions (MULTI/EXEC) enough for you?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer - My knowledge is limited in Redis. Structure I am storing in the hash.
Will the sequence as follow works in C:-
MULTI -> HGET -> some action on structure like updating some fields in the structure -> HSET -> EXEC

Comment: You can't observe the values using a transaction. If that's what you need, perhaps a Lua script would be better. It runs atomically until it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Redis provides the following:

1) Use Redis transactions and optimistic locking. See [Redis Transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions)

2) Or Lua scripting, which will be executed in Redis atomically. See [EVAL](https://redis.io/commands/eval)

Answer (score 0):

Use the watch command https://redis.io/commands/watch to detect modification by other clients. This command is specified only to the specified keys in redis transactions

Answer (score 0):

Dears, thanks all for your response. It was helpful to know various features and generalised way available with the redis.

However I approached as follows as my requirement met this way.

I used secound timestamp (say t_sec) as key and counter as hash value. If in that particular second, further request comes, the counter value corresponding to t_sec key was incremented (HINCRBY command) in atomic way. Rest of the parameters are locally stored in a structure. If counter reaches a particular set limit, requests were dropped. 
If this is next sec, new t_sec key value is used and counter is incremented from zero. 
t_sec key corresponding to previous second got deleted (HDEL command).